# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

I have a tests project that I am trying to test my nhibernate layer with using sql lite in-memory database.

I'm getting the error:

**Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000,**

```
private void CreateSessionFactory()
{
            _sessionFactory = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(_dbType)
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => _configuration = cfg)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

I'm using fluentnhibernate, and nunit also.

What could the issue be?

**Update**

I downloaded the x64 (i'm on windows 7 64-bit) from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki  and now I'm getting this error:

```
 Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.DLL': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

If I try and add the Interop.dll in vs.net 2010, it doesn't let me saying it could not be added, make sure it is valid etc.

Answer (score 5):

Latest version of [SQLite for .NET](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) is distributed as 2 dlls.

- System.Data.SQLite.dll
- SQLite.Interop.dll

Both dlls need to be present in the same folder as your EXE. Interop dll is platform specific so you have to manually (or Post-build) copy x86 or x64 version.

Another thing to keep in mind is that **SQLite.Interop.dll** itslef depends on **MSVCR100.DLL** (part of Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package). You can get it here:

- [64 bit version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13523)
- [32 bit version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328)

Comment: any ideas why it refuses to add to my project when I add it via 'add reference', sql.data.sqlite added fine.

Comment: *SQLite.Interop.dll* is not a managed dll you can not add it as a reference to a .NET project. It should be copied manually.

Comment: this no longer applies. if you run the sqlite installer on windows, it builds the ineterop into the main System.Data.SQLite.dll. this is the only thing you need to bring along to the party