# How to read a Version 2 Sqlite database from .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Seems that `System.Data.SQLite` supports only version 3. What to use to read version 2? I don't want to use the `sqlite3.dll` directly because it only supports 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html):

> Format 2 adds the ability of rows within the same table to have a
>   varying number of columns, in order to support the ALTER TABLE ... ADD
>   COLUMN functionality. Support for reading and writing format 2 was
>   added in SQLite version **3.1.3** on 2005-02-19.

Latest version of SQLite for .NET is actually [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) (not at phxsoftware.com anymore). They distribute x86 and x64 bit versions. The latest release supports SQLite **3.7.7.1** so it should be able to read V2 file. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493840/could-not-create-the-driver-from-nhibernate-driver-sqlite20driver-nhibernate-ve/7493910#7493910) for some details.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't open version 2. I also recompiled sqlite3 for x64, but it crashed in my c# app. So finally I was forced to make another 32bit exe to help my 64bit app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/? Their latest version has a x64 ADO.NET provider for SQLite 3.